# htaccess in many folders

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I'm new in htaccess  and I'm developing a stuff like modules

and I want that each module has his own htaccess (private one)
for example

- folder1

  - htaccess
- folder2

  - htaccess
- folder3

  - htaccess

and all those folders are mapped with a global htaccess (public one)

When the request comes  it is passed to global htaccess at his turn if he finds the matching folder redirects it and it is matter to private htaccess at this time

the question is : is it possible to implement it ?
and how can i redirect from htaccess to another ?

Comment: So what's your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that .htaccess files in child folders are processed prior to any .htaccess files in parent folders, so in essence you will get your desired behavior by default.  The challenge with your approach is going to be in making sure the interactions between these files work as expected.

To me, any application with a reasonable amount of routing complexity might need to consider the implementation of a universal routing mechanism in code (i.e. front controller/router pattern). You could do this while still deferring actual routing logic to your modules.

Comment: i took this approach with one purpose in mind  " have  independent modules" that we can plug in out without any difficulty instead of processing the request with my own routers (like frameworks do symfony2 & zend 2 ...) which time consuming and performance decreasing

Comment: @user1825286 The problem with that approach is that there is always going to be an interaction with the parent .htaccess file unless you do something like redirect all requests in that sub-directory to a router that is used for that sub-directory only. In other words you would need to 100% prevent any requests from getting as far as the parent .htaccess file if you want to guarantee that the module can work independently and not be effected by changes in the parent .htaccess

Comment: great my friend i got exactly what i have expected thank you for your precious explanation your are cool